# How to read a text file in browser with JavaScript that is located within the project folder?

Tags: javascript

I have a text file named "test.txt" and I want to get its text in string format using javascript. The contents are used to fill html templates that will populate the web page but I don't know how to retrieve the text.

I found FileReader but ran into issues when specifying a file path then later discovered it only works with files selected by users. Then I found FileSystem and tried to add it in with this code but ran into issues with "require" since it is not defined.

```
const fs = require('fs');

function LoadProjectCards(){
    let fileText = "";
    fs.readFile('test.txt', function (err, data) {
        fileText = data;
    });

    console.log(fileText);
}
```

later I found out that this is a Node.js module and that is a server side technology. My site is hosted on github pages and I do not have a server to use.

How do I read a file within the project files in a browser with javascript?

Comment: You need to include it in the static folder and then just import it should be enough. If you can access that text file with URL directly, then you can import it from JS too.
const myText = require('/static/text.txt');

Comment: @TaaviKivimaa Can you explain more? What do you mean by I need to include it in the static folder?

Answer (score 1):

**require** is not available in the browser. It's what available in the Nodejs. Also, The **fs** module can only work under **Nodejs** environment and not directly in the browser environment.

If you want to use the **require** in the browser you need run your code using **webpack** js bundler.

To read file, You can do something like

```
 fetch("test.txt")
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text));
```

considering test.txt is sibling with your current file.

(Note*
The **[fs](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp)** is native, a built-in module in **Node.js** that provides an API for working with the file system. It allows you to read, write, and manipulate files and directories.)

Comment: I am unsure what a webpack js bundler is. Is this just a way to make nodejs work in browsers? I also tried your code but it doesn't seem to work for me. I get an error saying that access to fetch from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Coss origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.